# nginx rewrite specific .css url to specific .php url

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm assuming this is an easy one for anyone with `nginx` knowledge.

I'm calling a URL like this:

```
/site-preview/css/custom-styles.css?org=myorg
```

The file `custom-styles.css` doesn't actually exist. So, I want to rewrite the URL to actually serve this:

```
/css/custom-styles.php?org=myorg
```

I'm coming from the apache world where I have this working in my `.htaccess` file.

In my `nginx` config I've tried things like:

```
location /site-preview {
    rewrite ^/site-preview/css/custom-styles.css?(.*) /css/custom-styles.php?$1 last;
}
```

and:

```
location /site-preview {
    rewrite ^css/custom-styles.css?(.*) /css/custom-styles.php?$1 last;
}
```

as well as having the `rewrite` outside of a `location` block.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your rewrite rules are for the extension `.cs` and `.css` followed by anything or nothing; the second example won't match anything since the path always starts with `/`. Probably a good idea to look at [the docs for $args, $is_args etc.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) - get args are not in the string the rewrite directive processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nginx documentation for rewrite (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) states that unless you end the replacement string with a '?' all previous qstring vars are appended. This means you don't need to (and probably shouldn't be) adding your qstring vars to the replacement.

Also I would be as specific as I could be on the location (adding ../css/.. path:

```
location /site-preview/css {
  # this is a blind rewrite passing qstr along
  rewrite custom-styles.css /css/custom-styles.php last;

  # this one does NOT pass along qstr (using the trailing '?')
  rewrite custom-styles.css /css/custom-styles.php? last;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I eventually figured that bit out about the query string and ended up with something very similar to what you have.